# Highcharts shift taking off too many points at the start

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

My chart has multiple series and when I try to add a new point and enable shift to true in the addpoint function on the series it seems to take too many points off.  My requestData function runs an ajax query which hits my api and brings back data.  The initial load loads in data just fine, however after the first points being added to the series it seems to take off too many points off some of the series.

Here is what it looks initial load

https://gyazo.com/51a2afc465f8fbb625e384e75d52b865

and here is what it looks like after one and two requests:

https://gyazo.com/0b523e4675c681b7495a38660b4de72c

https://gyazo.com/5cf7e9498ab3b34f3eaac1cf50a0bdc5

Here is my code for requesting data:

```
function requestData(chart1, start, devID, attrib) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/MetricsAPI/',
    data: {
        deviceID: devID,
        attribute: attrib,
        startDate: start
    },
    success: function (dataset) {
        var chartSeries = chart1.series;
        for (var index = 0; index < dataset.length; index++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < chartSeries.length; i++) {
                if (chartSeries[i].name == dataset[index].attribute) {
                    var shift = chartSeries[i].data.length > 12;
                    chartSeries[i].addPoint([parseInt(dataset[index].epochTime), dataset[index].value], true, shift);
                    console.log('date: ' + dataset[index].epochTime + ', ' + 'value: ' + dataset[index].value);
                }
            }
        }
        chart1.redraw();
        //call it again after one minute
        setTimeout(requestData, 30000, chart1, dataset[dataset.length - 1].epochTime, devID, attrib);
    },
    failure: function (xhr, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(error);
    },
    cache: false
});
}
```

Comment: Could you set `chartSeries[i].addPoint([parseInt(dataset[index].epochTime), dataset[index].value], true, shift);` redraw param to false (`true`=>`false`)?

Comment: @Pawel Fus I will try that

Comment: Also, I would suggest to double check this condition: `chartSeries[i].name == dataset[index].attribute` - it may happen you are adding multiple points with the same timestamp for one series, so points are not visible, but multiple points are removed. Have you considered setting `series.id` and then using `chart.get(id)` to add points to proper series? Of course, ID's must be distinct.

Comment: @PawełFus that did the trick! can you put it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible issues with current code:

- set `redraw` param to false, here: `chartSeries[i].addPoint([parseInt(dataset[index].epochTime), dataset[index].value], true, shift);`
- set `series.id` and avoid comparing `chartSeries[i].name == dataset[index].attribute`. Instead to get correct series use `chart.get(id)`.

Comment: Multiple points were being added to the same spot which caused the lines to remove from the end which you mentioned, should probably add that in.  I just added a check to see if that point is within the xData property of the series.